# Combine two (or multiple) columns of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, coalesce

I have a table

```
a   b   c
1   2   
1   3   
1   4   1
2   1   2
```

The column a and c should be combined if the value is the same. If there are not the same, it is always so that one is empty

So the result should be:

```
a    b 
1    2    
1    3    
1    4
2    1
```

Is there any function that can be applied in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Perhaps you should extend your case, 'cos desired results can be obtained via `SELECT a,b FROM tab`

Comment: A test case should include all relevant cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description:

> The column a and c should be combined if the value is the same. If
>   there are not the same, it is always so that one is empty

all you need is an unconditional [**`COALESCE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, c) AS a, b FROM tbl;
```

Assuming that by "empty" you mean `NULL`, not an empty string (`''`), in which case you'd add [`NULLIF`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(a, ''), c) AS a, b FROM tbl;
```

`COALESCE` works for multiple parameters:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, c, d, e, f, g) AS a, b FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT COALESCE(c, a), b
FROM your_table
WHERE COALESCE(c, a) = a
```